# Is it possible to detect a fingerprint when a touch occurs?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the fingerprint of users when they touch an android device display. Is there any way to do this ?

Something like this :

[image: Fingerprint]

Thanks.

Comment: You mean getting the finger print ? Then you should make it more clear.

Comment: Yes that's true. Simple i mean fingerprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is no. The touch screen just isn't sensitive enough to be able to detect differences in pressure that minute or differentiate between touches that close together.

Comment: Ok. I can't scan fingerprint. Can i atleast get circle of pressed finger. It's all that i need.

Comment: This could potentially depend on the device in question. But what might be easier to implement is checking if the motionevent was made by a finger (which is as simple as just asking the event) and then placing an image (like the one above). What is it that you're after?

Comment: i don't need draw something on place where is finger. i am only asking for some way to get more than one point per finger. That's all.

Comment: This aged like milk.

Answer (score 2):

sorry, it's not possible. The touch sensors are based on an electric current passing from your finger to the screen, while finger print sensors would need to analyze the oils coming off your fingers. We're not there yet!

Comment: Yes but there can be multiple electronic sources or not?

Comment: Yup, for example in multitouch or using a stylus in addition to your fingers and maybe your toe too whilst you're at it.